# GeoDjango bounding box filter usage

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a bounding box query to find all UserProfile objects that are contained within a bounding box specified by (swLat, swLon, neLat, neLon). Despite setting the point to be centered within the bounding box, an empty array is being returned. Below is my model and query code.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def setLocation(self, lat, lon):
        if not self.location:
            self.location = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%s %s)' % (lat, lon))
        else:
            self.location.set_x(float(lat))
            self.location.set_y(float(lon))
        self.save()

from models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon
class SomeView:
    def getUserProfilesWithinBBox(swMapBoundsLat, swMapBoundsLon, neMapBoundsLat, neMapBoundsLon, userProfileLocationLat, userProfileLocationLon, userProfile):
        '''neMapBoundsLat=38.908254,neMapBoundsLon=-77.002034
           swMapBoundsLat=38.888515,seMapBoundsLon-77.070698
           userProfileLocationLat=38.89838500999149, userProfileLocationLon=-77.03636580000001
        '''
        userProfile.setLocation(userProfileLat, userProfileLon)
        geom = Polygon.from_bbox((swMapBoundsLat, swMapBoundsLon, neMapBoundsLat, neMapBoundsLon))
        matchingUserProfiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(location__bbcontains=geom)
        # matchingUserProfiles should contain the userProfile that was just saved, but is always an empty list. what am I doing wrong?
        return matchingUserProfiles
```

Background info:

- Database backend: Postgresql-8.4 & PostGIS 1.5.8
- Django 1.4.3
- OS: Ubuntu 12.04x32

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks guys,
Matt

Comment: Nevermind, got it figured out. I needed to use 'within' since I wanted to see if the point was within the bounding box and not if the bounding box was in the point (duh! :P)


    matchingUserProfiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(location__within=geom)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to sort the profiles by their proximity to the center of the bounding box.

```
center = Point(float(lat), float(lng)) # lat/lng of the center of the bounding box
geo_query = Q(point__within=geom)
UserProfile.objects.filter(geo_query).distance(center).order_by('distance')
```